# windows phone xml filter

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone

I am trying to develop an app for a TV channel. I have an XML file and have parsed it. Now the problem is that i want to filter it. Here is the XML file:

http://top-channel.tv/rss/videofeed.xml

i want to filter those by category but want to filter category 3, 5, 6 in one page and category 25, 99 etc on other page. I have use this:

When I click on the button to open the webpage with http://youtube.com/whatch?v= + icon that is on the LajmeVideo.icon. This is all my source code

```
namespace Top_Channel
{
    public partial class Video : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Video()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            grdLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;

            WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
            webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webclient_DownloadStringCompleted);
            webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://top-channel.tv/rss/videofeed.xml"));
        }

        void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Ju lutem verifikoni qe te keni internet ne telefonin tuaj", "Ska Internet", MessageBoxButton.OK);

            }

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
            var videos = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "video");
            List<LajmeVideo> lajmes = new List<LajmeVideo>();
            foreach (var item in videos)
            {
                var category = item.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "category").FirstOrDefault();
                var title = item.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "title").FirstOrDefault();
                var icon = item.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "youtubeid").FirstOrDefault();
                if (category.Value == "25" || category.Value == "99")
                {
                    lajmes.Add(new LajmeVideo()
                    {
                        kategoria = category.Value,
                        title = title.Value,
                        icon = icon.Value,
                    });
                }
                lajme_video.ItemsSource = lajmes;
                var uri = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + item.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "youtubeid").FirstOrDefault().Value);
            }

            progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
            grdLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
            webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=My2FRPA3Gf8", UriKind.Absolute);
            webBrowserTask.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(Properties.Resources.videofeed);
        var videos = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "video");
        List<LajmeVideo> lajmes = new List<LajmeVideo>();
        foreach (var item in videos)
        {
            var cat = item.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "category").FirstOrDefault();
            if (cat.Value == "25" || cat.Value == "99")
            {
                //addtolist;
            }
            var uri = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + item.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "youtubeid").FirstOrDefault().Value);
        }
```

Comment: it get me error in: var videos   (videos is with red line)

var videos = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "video");
        List<LajmeVideo> lajmes = new List<LajmeVideo>();
        foreach (var item in videos)

Comment: I have writed all my source code on top.i get error on XDocument doc = Xdocument.Parse(Properties.Resources.videofeed); The error is on Properties and says that "The name "Properties" does not exist in the current contex "

Comment: It was just my way how to load a document, in your case you put e.Result.

Comment: can you please copy my source and replace with the correct one,or send me the correct with email ardit_dine@hotmail.com

Comment: i have fixed it but on the //addtolist item it gave me error.Can you please teall me how to fix it? it say the same thing "The name "title" does not exist in the current contex " and how can i write it on the Button_Click?

Comment: Post your whole current code, I don't get what error you mean

Comment: i have posted the code,i get error on:
title = weather.Element("title").Value,
                                      icon = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + weather.Element("youtubeid").Value + "/2.jpg",
                                      kategoria = weather.Element("category").Value,

Comment: Create the class LajmeVideo with properties Id, Title, Category etc... In foreach loop create a variable category = item.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "category").FirstOrDefault(); title = item.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "category").FirstOrDefault(); etc. AFter that write lajmes.Add(new LajmeVide(){title = title.Value, category = car.valie}); ...

Comment: can you please view me updated code,i get everything right with no error but i get only one item display on my app.and the category filter don't work well

Comment: the problem now is that because on the category i have writed var category = item.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "category").FirstOrDefault; and in if (category.Value == "12" || category.Value == "25" || category.Value == "27") if the first item of the xml have the value 27 or 25 or 12 it display only the first one,but if the first item on the xml don't have any of those value on the category all the item with those category will display.how can i solve this? and what should i write on the Button_Click to open the youtube url + youtubeid?

Comment: var title = item.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "category").FirstOrDefault();
            var icon = item.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "category").FirstOrDefault();
 this is wrong

Comment: sorry, i know that the var icon = ... was wrong and now i fixed it but i still get only the first item

Comment: there are about 100 item